# Can this Recurrence Relation be semplified?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have the following Recurrence Relation
$$        \begin{equation}
        T(n)=
        \begin{cases}
        \Theta(1), & \text{if}\ n=1 \\
        3T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor) + \Theta(n), & \text{if}\ 1 < n < n_0 \\
        3T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor) + cn, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}$$
where $\Theta(n)$ is an anonymous function $f(n)$ such that $f(n) \leq cn, \ \forall n \geq n_0$.

I'd like to know if
$$        \begin{equation}
        S(n)=
        \begin{cases}
        \Theta(1), & \text{if}\ n=1 \\
        3T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor) + cn, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}$$
is an upper bound for $T(n)$

I tried to prove it, but since we do not know wether $f(n)$ is less than or greater than $cn$ for each $n < n_0$, I was not able to prove that $3T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor) + cn$ for all $n>1$

Comment: Start should be at $0$, as $T(2)$ (if $2 < n_0)$ depends on $T(0)$.